# Why jspx is displayed like xml?

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, web, jspx

I was create index.jspx document in 'web' folder. It contain:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
      <html>
        <head><title>Calculator</title></head>
        <jsp:include page="style.css"/>
        <body>
          <form name = "calculator" action="calculate" method="post" onsubmit="prepareData()">
            <input type="hidden" name ="operandModified" id ="operandModified" value="${indicator}"/>
           </form>
        </body>
      </html>
    </jsp:root>
```

I use tomcat. I want it to be displayed as .jsp.
Maybe I do not understand anything about the concept of jspx?

I configure web.xml like this:

---

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <is-xml>true</is-xml>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

---

Why when i go to localhost:8080/index.jspx, page is displayed as xml document?

Comment: AFAIK .jspx is an IBM specific extension - what we server are you using? Port 8080 sounds like Tomcat.

Comment: Well Tomcat is unaware that .jspx is anything special, so it will turn it over to whatever handler exists on the browser. This is likely to default to a text editor - hence the XML dispaly. What are you expecting the .jspx file to do?

Comment: My task is 'convert' .jsp page in my project to .jspx format.

Comment: But Tomcat does not recognise .jspx as anything special. You will need to test on a Websphere installation, which recognises this format. What result do you expect from Tomcat?

Comment: I want it to be displayed as .jsp. Maybe I do not understand anything about the concept of jspx?

Comment: You could be right there :) The only place I have seen .jspx files is in IBM Websphere Portal, where they are used to define user menus. Apologies if they are used in places that I am unaware of.

Comment: Tomcat recognizes and handles jspx as jsp. Look into tomcat_dir/conf/web.xml (jsp servlet mapping).

Comment: Thanks to all!
I just add
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
and browser display my page like html :)